# How do I trigger the window load event in this Jest test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jestjs

I'm trying to set up my first DOM-manipulation/JQuery Jest test in my Rails project. In its essential form at the moment, I'm just trying to clear a basic hurdle of 'imported Javascript functions do anything at all'.

To that end, I have the following code in PledgeFormUpdates.js.test:

```
'use strict';

import pledge_form_updates from '../../app/javascript/components/PledgeFormUpdates.js';

test('Displays GDPR checkbox on EU country selection', () => {

  // Set up our document body
  document.body.innerHTML =
    '<select id="pledge_pledgor_home_country" class="country-select"></select>'// +

    pledge_form_updates();
    const $ = require('jquery');

    $(window).trigger('load');
    $("#pledge_pledgor_home_country").trigger('change');
});
```

And in PledgeFormUpdates.js I have the following:

```
export default function() {
  console.log('hello world');
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    console.log('mellow curled');
    $("#pledge_pledgor_home_country").change(function() {
      console.log('yellow twirled')
    });
  });
};
```

So when I run the test, I'm expecting to see printout including 'hello world', 'mellow curled' and 'yellow twirled'. But in practice it's stopping after the first output, and so presumably the window `load` event isn't actually getting triggered (which I confirmed by commenting out the `window.addEventListener...` line, then seeing all three printouts).

What am I doing wrong here - or rather, how *should* I trigger the load event? (I also tried `$(window).load();`, but that just raises a TypeError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, though it seems quite hacky. In the tested file, if I substitute the line

`window.addEventListener("load", function() {`,

with

`$(window).on("load", function() {`

then running the test (including the `$(window).trigger('load');` statement) prints all of the log lines.

I must be missing something, because I can't believe that Jest would *require* JQuery to trigger a page load event, but for now at least this works.